# Found at an Estate sale

Tags: identify-this-bike, evaluation

[image]

I have an opportunity to buy this bicycle. No idea what it is or what its worth. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Mike. That is one beautiful bike! Unfortunately, we cannot do valuations here. It's really worth what you think it is. Look for corrosion and degradation of the tires. IMO if you can get it for $10 to $50, it would be a bargain. But who knows what a collector would pay? I was running such a sale once, and a collector asked what I wanted for some old oil drums, that were just lying about. Thinking quickly, I said ah ... ten bucks! Done! An hour later another guy saw them an offered $50! You never know what collectors will pay.

Comment: Any idea what it is? All I have to go by is the pic until I can see it on Saturday. I've scoured the internet trying to find anything about it.

Comment: Sorry, absolutely no idea :-)

Comment: WOW! That's pretty sweet! would look awesome restored

Comment: Klaster_1 found that _some_ are people willing to pay $350 for it. How much is it worth to _you_ is the real question.

Comment: Its a 1950's motorbike-style bike.  The chain guard and step-through design suggests a ladies bike, as does the suspension.  It looks in decent condition, so could be a nice project for a refurb.   Probably not the best of rides though.

Answer (score 15):

It's a JC Higgins Jet Flow from about 1953-57. [Here's a forum thread](http://thecabe.com/forum/threads/higgins-jet-flow.8115/) where people are ready to pay $350+ for one in pristine condition.

Comment: Wow! Great work!

Comment: In case someone wonders how I google that: first, I've started with basic assumption about bike being a 50s cruiser. Scrolling through found image didn't help at all. Next thing I tried was to get a list of 50s major cruiser manufaturers and query "x 50s cruiser". No luck too. Next clue was to look for women models because of sloped frame. This way I found out that slotted thing over rear is called "skirt guard". The "cruiser skirt guard front suspension ladies" produced a portion of same looking bike, which led to provided forum thread after reverse image search. Google is awesome.